# Скорость загрузки Google PageSpeed Insights

Tags: css, html5, оптимизация-сайтов, pagespeed-insights

Я оптимизировал css код с помощью gulp, убрал не нужный код и минифицировал стили. На проверке скорости оптимизации гугл выдаёт, что надо сократить неиспользуемый css и минифицировать его. Ссылка на сам сайт.
https://vashkaweb.ru/work/sait/
Также ссылка на проверку от гугла:
[https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=ru&url=https%3A%2F%2Fvashkaweb.ru%2Fwork%2Fsait%2F&tab=mobile]
Можете объяснить в чём суть проблемы?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вопрос то в чем? Вы хотите чтобы за вас сократили ваш код и минифицировали его?

Comment: У меня ощущение, что вы не прочитали вопрос..... Я уже это сделал, с помощью gulp, но гугл выдаёт, что это не сделано. Я же написал вначале, что всё это уже сделано....

Comment: О, эти гугл инструменты постоянно выдают хитрые и взаимоисключающие ситуации. Выполнил одну - нарушил другую, чтобы поправить вторую даётся рекомендация нарушить первую. Так что поправить все-все-все рекомендации не так-то и просто, если у вас не сайт-визитка, в более сложных случаях приходится чем-то жертвовать и искать пути соблюдения баланса.

Comment: Это кончено да. Но меня поразило, что гугл в рекомендациях выдаёт, что надо минифицировать стили

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Указанный вами тестер скорости загрузки веб-страниц на мобильные устройства сообщает вам, в секции **Возможности**, следующие рекомендации по оптимизации этой скорости:

**Удалите неиспользуемый код CSS**. Если вы щелкните по этой рекомендации, то там откроется некоторый текст и текстовая ссылка *Подробнее*... 
Если вы перейдете по этой ссылке, то вас перенаправят на руководство Гугл Отложить неиспользованный CSS. В этом руководстве есть много полезной информации и рекомендаций. Например:

> По умолчанию браузер должен загрузить, проанализировать и обработать
>   все внешние таблицы стилей, с которыми он сталкивается, прежде чем он
>   сможет отображать или отображать любой контент на экране пользователя.
>   Для браузера не имеет смысла пытаться отображать содержимое до того,
>   как таблицы стилей были обработаны, потому что таблицы стилей могут
>   содержать правила, которые влияют на стилизацию страницы.
>
> Каждая внешняя таблица стилей должна быть загружена из сети. Эти
>   дополнительные сетевые поездки могут значительно увеличить время,
>   которое пользователи должны ждать, прежде чем они увидят какой-либо
>   контент на своих экранах.
>
> Неиспользуемый CSS также замедляет построение дерева рендеринга
>   браузером . Дерево рендеринга похоже на дерево DOM, за исключением
>   того, что оно также включает в себя стили для каждого узла. Чтобы
>   построить дерево визуализации, браузер должен пройтись по всему дереву
>   DOM и проверить, какие правила CSS применяются к каждому узлу. Чем
>   больше неиспользуемого CSS, тем больше времени может понадобиться
>   браузеру для расчета стилей для каждого узла.

Там также дают вам рекомендации для оптимизации ваших стилей, например:

> CSS, необходимый для загрузки страницы, называется **критическим
>   CSS**. Как правило, загрузка страницы должна блокироваться только на
>   критических CSS.  Теоретически, наиболее оптимальный подход - встроить
>   критический CSS в HTML. Как только HTML загружен, браузер имеет
>   все, что ему нужно для отображения страницы. Больше не нужно делать
>   сетевые запросы. **[Смотрите встраивание CSS](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/unused-css)**.
>
> **Некритический CSS** - это CSS, который может понадобиться странице позже. Например, предположим, что нажатие кнопки вызывает модальное
>   появление. Модал появляется только после нажатия кнопки. Правила стиля
>   модала некритичны, потому что модал никогда не будет отображаться при
>   первой загрузке страницы.

Таким образом вы можете использовать следующие возможности для оптимизации скорости загрузки ваших стилей. 
Пересмотрите ваш внешний файл стилей и выберите из него только те стили которые требуются для загрузки критического CSS, то есть те правила стилей без которых веб-страница будет показана с какими то явными искажениями дизайна. Установите эти отобранные стили внутрь **[HTML элемента head](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_head.asp)**.

Пересмотрите иерархическую структуру веб-страницы. Оставьте в прямом потоке загрузки только содержание которое имеет наиболее важную информацию. Например, вызывает некоторое сомнение тот факт, что ваш баннер с информацией о том, что "Реклама - двигатель торговли", является важной информацией. Также вызывает сомнение в важности слайд-шоу, которое расположено ниже. По моему скромному мнению, все то же самое, относиться к всей последующей информации. Если вы всю эту информацию установите в аккордеонах или в модульных всплывающих окнах, то тем самым вы удалите много информации из прямого потока загрузки. Для этой, второстепенной и неважной информации, стили будут не критичными и это означает что скорость загрузки повысится. 
Кроме того, для дизайна UX, важно понимать, что человек может за один раз воспринимать максимально 7 объектов на веб-странице и оптимальное количество объектов равно 5. Избыточная информация может путать пользователя и он будет уходить без действий и без конверсии.

**Включите сжатие текста**. Проделайте те же самые действия, которые я сообщил выше и проверьте **[руководство Гугл для сжатия текста](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/text-compression)**. В этом руководстве вы найдете текстовую ссылку для **[конфигурации сервера](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs)**. Проверьте эту информацию, возможно это может быть полезным для оптимизации скорости загрузки вашей веб-страницы.

**Используйте современные форматы изображений**. Для анализа критичных ресурсов, особенно изображений, используйте бесплатный онлайн инструмент webpagetest и выберите наиболее старую модель смартфона для тестирования. Этот инструмент создает **[три версии анализа веб-страницы такие как Waterfall](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/191010_HY_4b9a32e1d38ec2526fe7d619374f3b3c/)**. Выберите наиболее низкую скорость загрузки, например Run 1 и щелкните по нему. Вам покажут **[информацию с ресурсами анализируемой веб-страницы](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/191010_HY_4b9a32e1d38ec2526fe7d619374f3b3c/1/details/#waterfall_view_step1)**, например список загружаемых внешних ресурсов = 57.

> 1 https://vashkaweb.ru/work/sait/ text/html   0.791 s 61 ms   244 ms  451
>   ms    283 ms  178 ms  28.6 KB -   200 -
>   2 https://vashkaweb.ru...rk/sait/img/user.svg image/svg+xml   1.217
>   s -   -   -   358 ms  61 ms   1.2 KB  -   200 -
>   3 https://vashkaweb.ru...it/css/style.min.css text/css    1.218
>   s -   -   -   178 ms  1135 ms 214.2 KB    -   200 -
>   4 https://vashkaweb.ru...it/img/megaphone.png image/png   1.218
>   s -   -   -   366 ms  104 ms  3.7 KB  -   200 -
>   5 https://vashkaweb.ru...k/sait/img/paint.png image/png   1.219
>   s -   -   -   363 ms  101 ms  4.6 KB  -   200 -
>   6 https://vashkaweb.ru...sait/img/printer.png image/png   1.22
>   s -   -   -   360 ms  109 ms  1.1 KB  -   200 -
>   7 https://vashkaweb.ru...k/sait/img/tools.png image/png   1.22
>   s -   -   -   357 ms  114 ms  2.2 KB  -   200 -
>   8 https://vashkaweb.ru...mg/advantagesSl1.png image/png   1.221
>   s -   -   -   401 ms  1323 ms 93.6 KB -   200 -
>   9 https://vashkaweb.ru...mg/advantagesSl2.png image/png   1.221
>   s -   -   -   353 ms  1372 ms 158.7 KB    -   200 -
>   10    https://vashkaweb.ru...rk/sait/img/logo.png image/png   1.229
>   s -   -   -   372 ms  96 ms   3.5 KB  -   200 -
>   11    https://vashkaweb.ru...it/img/promotion.png image/png   1.25
>   s -   -   -   345 ms  474 ms  3.1 KB  -   200 -
>   12    https://vashkaweb.ru...k/sait/img/start.png image/png   1.252
>   s -   -   -   345 ms  465 ms  2.7 KB  -   200 -
>   13    https://vashkaweb.ru.../sait/img/rating.png image/png   1.252
>   s -   -   -   342 ms  465 ms  2.6 KB  -   200 -
>   14    https://vashkaweb.ru.../sait/img/podium.png image/png   1.253
>   s -   -   -   345 ms  468 ms  0.9 KB  -   200 -
>   15    https://vashkaweb.ru.../sait/img/global.png image/png   1.255
>   s -   -   -   345 ms  472 ms  0.8 KB  -   200 -
>   16    https://vashkaweb.ru...ait/img/photo_sl.png image/png   1.261
>   s -   -   -   340 ms  489 ms  42.6 KB -   200 -
>   17    https://vashkaweb.ru...k/sait/img/close.png image/png   1.262
>   s -   -   -   339 ms  462 ms  0.5 KB  -   200 -
>   18    https://vashkaweb.ru...sait/img/popupsl.jpg image/jpeg  1.264
>   s -   -   -   335 ms  1348 ms 79.8 KB -   200 -
>   19    https://vashkaweb.ru...t/img/right-link.png image/png   1.264
>   s -   -   -   345 ms  455 ms  0.5 KB  -   200 -
>   20    https://vashkaweb.ru.../sait/img/Paypal.svg image/svg+xml   1.266
>   s -   -   -   335 ms  704 ms  7.7 KB  -   200 -
>   21    https://vashkaweb.ru...rk/sait/img/visa.svg image/svg+xml   1.267
>   s -   -   -   334 ms  713 ms  2.1 KB  -   200 -
>   22    https://vashkaweb.ru...t/img/mastercard.svg image/svg+xml   1.269
>   s -   -   -   334 ms  734 ms  8.8 KB  -   200 -
>   23    https://vashkaweb.ru...ait/img/computer.png image/png   1.269
>   s -   -   -   345 ms  395 ms  0.8 KB  -   200 -
>   24    https://vashkaweb.ru...rk/sait/img/bank.svg image/svg+xml   1.27
>   s -   -   -   332 ms  692 ms  1.2 KB  -   200 -
>   25    https://vashkaweb.ru.../img/right-arrow.png image/png   1.27
>   s -   -   -   345 ms  287 ms  0.6 KB  -   200 -
>   26    https://vashkaweb.ru...k/sait/img/purse.svg image/svg+xml   1.27
>   s -   -   -   330 ms  616 ms  1.0 KB  -   200 -
>   27    https://vashkaweb.ru...ait/img/sberbank.svg image/svg+xml   1.272
>   s -   -   -   331 ms  619 ms  3.1 KB  -   200 -
>   28    https://vashkaweb.ru...t/img/left-arrow.png image/png   1.273
>   s -   -   -   345 ms  396 ms  0.6 KB  -   200 -
>   29    https://vashkaweb.ru...mg/advantagesSl3.png image/png   1.274
>   s -   -   -   345 ms  376 ms  55.1 KB -   200 -
>   30    https://vashkaweb.ru...rk/sait/img/cash.svg image/svg+xml   1.274
>   s -   -   -   330 ms  707 ms  3.0 KB  -   200 -
>   31    https://vashkaweb.ru...ait/img/facebook.svg image/svg+xml   1.275
>   s -   -   -   328 ms  726 ms  1.2 KB  -   200 -
>   32    https://vashkaweb.ru...work/sait/img/vk.svg image/svg+xml   1.275
>   s -   -   -   329 ms  719 ms  2.3 KB  -   200 -
>   33    https://vashkaweb.ru...work/sait/img/ok.svg image/svg+xml   1.276
>   s -   -   -   326 ms  716 ms  1.3 KB  -   200 -
>   34    https://vashkaweb.ru.../sait/img/google.svg image/svg+xml   1.277
>   s -   -   -   325 ms  724 ms  1.1 KB  -   200 -
>   35    https://vashkaweb.ru...k/sait/img/smail.svg image/svg+xml   1.277
>   s -   -   -   326 ms  739 ms  2.1 KB  -   200 -
>   36    https://vashkaweb.ru...sait/img/twitter.svg image/svg+xml   1.278
>   s -   -   -   324 ms  731 ms  1.4 KB  -   200 -
>   37    https://vashkaweb.ru...t/js/parallax.min.js application/javascript  1.279
>   s -   -   -   322 ms  728 ms  1.0 KB  -   200 -
>   38    https://vashkaweb.ru...rk/sait/js/slider.js application/javascript  1.28
>   s -   -   -   323 ms  726 ms  5.8 KB  -   200 -
>   39    https://vashkaweb.ru.../sait/js/main.min.js application/javascript  1.282
>   s -   -   -   321 ms  738 ms  14.4 KB -   200 -
>   40    https://cdnjs.cloudf...1.12.4/jquery.min.js application/javascript;
>   charset=utf-8 1.626 s 4 ms    47 ms   218 ms  57 ms   193 ms  94.9 KB -   200 -
>   41    https://fonts.google...700,800&display=swap text/css;
>   charset=utf-8 1.672 s 103 ms  47 ms   256 ms  58 ms   34 ms   9.7 KB  -   200 -
>   42    https://vashkaweb.ru...sait/img/indexbg.png image/png   2.694
>   s -   -   -   150 ms  1388 ms 426.0 KB    -   200 -
>   43    https://vashkaweb.ru...sait/img/faq_mob.png image/png   2.695
>   s -   -   -   291 ms  79 ms   20.7 KB -   200 -
>   44    https://vashkaweb.ru...work/sait/img/h2.png image/png   2.699
>   s -   -   -   776 ms  57 ms   0.4 KB  -   200 -
>   45    https://vashkaweb.ru...k/sait/img/sites.png image/png   2.703
>   s -   -   -   774 ms  1122 ms 93.1 KB -   200 -
>   46    https://vashkaweb.ru...tdoorAdvertising.png image/png   2.705
>   s -   -   -   771 ms  1141 ms 72.4 KB -   200 -
>   47    https://vashkaweb.ru...ork/sait/img/web.png image/png   2.705
>   s -   -   -   372 ms  73 ms   13.9 KB -   200 -
>   48    https://vashkaweb.ru...photographersMob.png image/png   2.708
>   s -   -   -   689 ms  1165 ms 110.6 KB    -   200 -
>   49    https://vashkaweb.ru.../sait/img/formbg.png image/png   2.711
>   s -   -   -   264 ms  1499 ms 205.4 KB    -   200 -
>   50    https://fonts.gstati...3g3D_vx3rCubqg.woff2 font/woff2  3.37
>   s -   -   -   362 ms  99 ms   8.3 KB  -   200 -
>   51    https://fonts.gstati...9W1hyyTh89ZNpQ.woff2 font/woff2  3.372
>   s -   -   -   264 ms  194 ms  8.4 KB  -   200 -
>   52    https://fonts.gstati...dJE3gnD_vx3rCs.woff2 font/woff2  3.372
>   s -   -   -   190 ms  146 ms  13.8 KB -   200 -
>   53    https://fonts.gstati...3g3D_vx3rCubqg.woff2 font/woff2  3.376
>   s -   -   -   357 ms  99 ms   8.3 KB  -   200 -
>   54    https://fonts.gstati...ZpC3gnD_vx3rCs.woff2 font/woff2  3.379
>   s -   -   -   113 ms  43 ms   13.8 KB -   200 -
>   55    https://fonts.gstati...3g3D_vx3rCubqg.woff2 font/woff2  3.38
>   s -   -   -   243 ms  170 ms  8.4 KB  -   200 -
>   56    https://fonts.gstati...m459WlhyyTh89Y.woff2 font/woff2  3.381
>   s -   -   -   198 ms  213 ms  13.8 KB -   200 -
>   57    https://fonts.gstati...bZF3gnD_vx3rCs.woff2 font/woff2  3.382 s 43
>   ms    54 ms   291 ms  117 ms  122 ms  13.6 KB -   200 -

Выберите наиболее важные ресурсы и удалите не важные. Например, вызывает сомнение тот факт, что для представления информации на этой веб-странице, требуются специальные шрифты, такие как woff2, которые вы здесь используете и которые имеют 8 внешних файлов (это 8 отдельных запроса сервера). Браузеры уже имеют встроенные шрифты, которые вы можете просто указать в стилях, например Verdana. 
Для оптимизации ваших изображения используйте следующие ресурсы:

- **[руководство Гугл для отзывчивых изображений](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/images)**
- **[руководство Гугл Автоматизация выбора ресурсов с помощью клиентских подсказок](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/automating-resource-selection-with-client-hints)**
- **[руководство Mozilla для отзывчивых изображений](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)**
- **[Применение srcset: выбор правильных размеров для адаптивных изображений в разных точках останова](https://medium.com/hceverything/applying-srcset-choosing-the-right-sizes-for-responsive-images-at-different-breakpoints-a0433450a4a3)**
- **[инструмент сжатия изображений Compress Image](https://compressnow.com/)** (я обычно использую 65% сжатие).

**Устраните ресурсы, блокирующие отображение**. Вероятно для этого вам могут помогать информация и мои рекомендации для первого пункта.

Для сжатия исходного кода веб-страницы вы можете использовать бесплатный онлайн инструмент **[HTML Compressor](https://htmlcompressor.com/compressor/)**. Кстати, если вы откроете исходный код этого инструмента, то там вы можете видеть, что все стили встроены внутрь HTML элемента head.

По моему скромному мнению, наилучшим решение для вашего веб-сайта может быть использование **[фреймворка АМП](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/)**, который рекомендует Гугл.